# Image Processing in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab

We try to multiplication operation of a black & white image with RGB image in same image but their class is not same: BW -> logical, RGB -> UINT8.

How can I convert from Logical to UNIT*? Or, can we do images which is in different class multiplication?

Comment: Could you please review my answer and mark it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a Binary (Logic) mask you want to multiply the image by.

It is easy:

```
mMask = double(mMaskBinary);

for ii = 1:numChannels

    mOutImage(:, :, ii) = mMask  .* mInputImage(:, :, ii);

end
```

In the latest MATLAB releases (From R2016b) expansion is done implicitly.
Hence if you want to do a multiplication between $ M \times N $ image to $ M \times N \times 3 $ image you can just multiply them element by element and the expansion to the 3rd dimension will happen automatically like in the loop above.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to convert type is: a=uint8(a) where a is your bw image.

I can convert to any type in this way e.g a=double(a).

For multiplication remember to use .* for element wise multiplication. * does matrix multiplication.